# Java - How to override a grandfather class method?

Tags: java, polymorphism

I have the following class structure:

```
 Abstract Class A
 Class B_A extends A
 
 Abstract Class C_A extends A
 
 Class D_CA extends CA
 Class E_CA extends CA
```

Class `A` implements a method name `do()`.

I'd like that Classes `B_A` and `D_CA` will use the method `do()` from the base class `A` but the I need `E_CA` class to override it and implement `do()` differently.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: What have you tried doing and where's the problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I override a method in a subclass?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5215612/how-do-i-override-a-method-in-a-subclass)

Comment: what is class CA

Answer (score 0):

You can simply override the `do()` method in `class E_CA`.

This will lead to every class inheriting from `E_CA` using the implementation in `E_CA` (unless it's overridden again). Every other class will use the implementation of `do()` in `A`

```
class E_CA extends CA {
    @Override
    public void do() {
        // new implementation
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all guys for your time.
I knew I had to use @override on the sub class.
But I had an error and it drove me crazy.
The problem was that the base class method was defined as private and the grandchild method was protected. Therefore it "yelled" on the sub class method.
Changing both of the implementations to **protected** fixed my problem.

Comment: Then kinda consider deleting your question. It wasnt exactly great, wasnt it ;-)

Comment: I think there is a warning that you *shouldnt* do it; but deleting a question with 0/negative scored answers should be possible; and is also a valid action to do so.